# how to compare heights values

Tags: php, sql

Hi
 i want know how to compare the height with other user height
here is my query

```
select * from tbl_Member where  height between 3'8''  and 7'0'';
```

here height is other user height
plz tell me correct query

Comment: what's your data type for the height column? Store it in units instead of text

Comment: And that's why you convert everything to sane values like centimeters first... :-P

Comment: You can't have unescaped quotes in your query string. then provide sample data and then ask what you want to do

Comment: Provide example data and the manufacturer of the database you are using.  Most likely you will want a stored procedure to convert.  Eg where toinch(height) >= toinch('3''8"') and toinch(height) <= toinch('3''8"');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's dirty, but here you go

```
select * 
from tbl_Member 
where 
   concat(format(left(height, 1), 0), lpad(format(substr(height,3,2), 0 ), 2, '0')) 
   between 308  and 700
```

3'8'' becomes 308
7'12'' becomes 712

Answer (score 4):

Comparing values like `3'8''` and `7'0''` in the database would require a lot of parsing for each query and be rather slow. Store your values in a comparable way in the database, which in this case means an `INT` column with values stored in centimeters. Put an index on it to make the query even faster. Then only convert to inches for display.

Comment: or even inches if you will (but not feet+inches), but you'll be better using the metric system : )

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the single-quotes inside of the varchar strings as the single-quote character indicates the start or the end of the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Member
WHERE height BETWEEN '3\'8\'\'' AND '7\'0\'\''
```